# Angular firebase persistence fetch new data from firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, persistence, offline

I created an angular 8 app with firestore using angularfirebase.
The app should work offline, this works fine by enabling persitence on firebase. (And create a serviceworker etc. for angular).
Now I fetch my data from firestore like this

```
public async get(): Promise<Customer[]> {
  return await this.itemsCollection.valueChanges({ idField: 'id' }).pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
}
```

I don't prefer the observables with async pipe approach because it makes everything too complex.

The problem I have now, if I update some data in firestore itself or on another device, the local data doesn't update. After I refresh the page, it keeps fetching the old cached firestore data.
I tried to fix this by clearing the persistence cache but I don't know where to put it in my code to make it work.

```
private db: AngularFirestore, // in constructor
this.db.firestore.clearPersistence(); // somewhere after initializing firebase
```

I also think that it's not a good production ready solution.

How can I solve this problem?
Maybe I should go for observables after all and rewrite everything.

Comment: Sounds like you do want an `Observable` which is a stream of data whereas a `Promise` only gives you a one off value. If you want values to be updating in real time, rethink using Async pipe with Observables.

Comment: no it doens't need to update in real time but when I refresh the page I expect the new data and not the local cached data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking that `valueChanges` here might not be the right approach. Since you don't need updates in real time, why not go with a simple `get` each page reload?

firebase source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document

a `get` call will return a `Promise` so no need to convert it. The `persistence` should only be an issue if you have the app offline. Clearing persistence is only recommended for testing purposes, so you'd be correct in avoiding it in production.

Example for angularfire, where .get() returns an observable:

```
public async get(): Promise<Customer[]> {
    return await this.itemsCollection.get().pipe(map(
      items => items.docs.map(doc => doc.data() as Customer)
    )).toPromise();
  }
```